# listをreturnさせるのがうまくいきません。

Tags: python, python3

Python3で質問です。
f(0)=1, f(1)=1, f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2), n>1と言う条件でnが1から20までの再帰を行いたいのですが

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return f(n-1)+f(n-2)
def main():
    for i in range(11):
        print(f(i))
main()
```

帰ってくる値は
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89

もともとのコードはこうなのですが、これをreturn時にlistに入れてreturnしたいのですがうまくいきません

```
def f(n):
    L = []
    ans = []
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        ans = 1
        L.append(ans)
        return L
    else:
        ans = f(n-1)+f(n-2)
        L.append(ans)
        return L
def main():
    for i in range(11):
        print(f(i))
main()
```

このように書くと上のような値が帰ってきません。

どのようにすればlistに入れてreturnさせてもうまくいきますか？
お知恵を貸してください

Answer (score 2):

別解として、以下の様に書いてみました。

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [1]
    elif n == 1:  
        return [1, 1]
    else:
        fn1 = f(n-1)
        return fn1 + [fn1[-1] + fn1[-2]]

def main():
    for i in range(11):
        print("f({0}) = {1}".format(i, f(i)))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

わざわざ関数1つでやる必要はありますか？

```
def g(n):
  if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return g(n-1)+g(n-2)

def f(n):
  l = []
  for i in range(n):
    l.append(g(i))
  return l

def main():
  print(f(11))

main()
```

このようにもう1つ関数を用意してしまうのがよいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

他の方と違うのも出来ました。もっとシンプルなのもありそうですかね。

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return [1]
    else:
        return [sum(f(n-1)) + sum(f(n-2))]
def fibonacci():
    result = []
    for i in range(11):
        result.append(f(i)[0])
    print(result)
fibonacci()
```

後は漸化式を解いてビネの公式を使う

```
from math import sqrt
def Fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return [1]
    else:
        return Fibonacci(n-1) + [(((1+sqrt(5))/2)**n-((1-sqrt(5))/2)**n)/(sqrt(5))]
def result():
    for i in range(1,12):
        print(Fibonacci(i))
result()
```

少し誤差が出ますが、

```
[1, 1.0]
[1, 1.0, 2.0]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001, 8.000000000000002]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001, 8.000000000000002, 13.000000000000002]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001, 8.000000000000002, 13.000000000000002, 21.000000000000004]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001, 8.000000000000002, 13.000000000000002, 21.000000000000004, 34.00000000000001]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001, 8.000000000000002, 13.000000000000002, 21.000000000000004, 34.00000000000001, 55.000000000000014]
[1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0000000000000004, 5.000000000000001, 8.000000000000002, 13.000000000000002, 21.000000000000004, 34.00000000000001, 55.000000000000014, 89.00000000000003]
```